# PDF (javascript) - How can i detect a global change on the form

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, pdf-generation, acrobat

My pdf form contain editText fields and a verification checkbox.
is there any way to detect changes in the editText fields ? (evry change will uncheck the checkbox).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a JavaScript action for KeyPress field event for each field. When the action is executed you can reset the value of the checkbox field.

Comment: this could difintly be a solution but i have many fields and my form will change from time to time. so im looking for a global solution

Comment: You can define a document level JavaScript function that resets the checkbox and call this function from each field's KeyPress action.

Comment: thanks, where can i define document level JavaScript function for my solution ?

Comment: In Adobe Acrobat go to View > Tools > JavaScript > Document JavaScripts